# Python 3.6.5, parallelism with multiprocessing.dummy.Pool.map()

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-3.6

So i'm trying to run certain function f(x) over a list l with Pool.map() as described in http://chriskiehl.com/article/parallelism-in-one-line. it goes like

```
pool = ThreadPool(8)
pool.map(f, l)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

The problem i ran into, is what it basically iterates over first seven items in the list, without proceeding any further, when expected behavior is assigning each eighth item for it's own thread, not sure how else to describe it, but you get the point. Like it's shown in the article. So, what's wrong here?

Comment: Please show us a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with imports, `f`and list.

Comment: Yeah, thank you actually, that helped me. Function was stuck in the infinite cycle and thus wasn't able to proceed further. Removing it solved the issue